# Balloon popup in dynamic display looks weird (with image link)

Tags: arcgis-engine

Here's how it looks when dynamic display is enabled
http://iterationx.posterous.com/34293301

Each letter gets its own balloon callout - this is quite annoying and I can't image why anyone would actually want this.

Here's the code I'm using, its in a custom dynamic layer:

```
public override void DrawDynamicLayer(esriDynamicDrawPhase DynamicDrawPhase, IDisplay iDisplay, IDynamicDisplay iDynamicDisplay) 
{
if (this.m_textGlyph == null)
{
IBalloonCallout balloonCallout = new BalloonCalloutClass();
balloonCallout.Style = esriBalloonCalloutStyle.esriBCSRoundedRectangle; //oval doesn't work 
ITextElement pTextElement = new TextElementClass();
TextSymbolClass textSymbolclass = new TextSymbolClass();
IFormattedTextSymbol balloonCalloutTextSymbol = textSymbolclass as IFormattedTextSymbol;
balloonCalloutTextSymbol.Background = balloonCallout as ITextBackground; 
balloonCalloutTextSymbol.Font = ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Connection.Local.Converter.ToStdFont(new Font("Arial", 10.0f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular));
m_textGlyph = dynamicGlyphFactory.CreateDynamicGlyph(balloonCalloutTextSymbol as ISymbol);
}

m_dynamicSymbolProperties.set_DynamicGlyph(esriDynamicSymbolType.esriDSymbolText, m_textGlyph);
dynamicDisplay.DrawText(mousePoint, textToDisplay);

}
```

edit:

I tried this but it looks the same

```
ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
Byte[] encodedBytes = ascii.GetBytes(textToDisplay);
String decodedString = ascii.GetString(encodedBytes);
dynamicDisplay.DrawText(mousePoint, decodedString);
```

---

Since I don't think there is going to be an answer, I'll just mention my workaround.

I created a Polygon to represent the Hover balloon, the simplified the geometry and drew text in the middle of it.  Then I kept a copy of the Balloon PointCollection in memory, and if the mapscale changes, I used a Transform2D, to move or scale it, depending on which was necessary.  The Glyph outline has to be the same as the fill color or you will get weird squares.

Comment: what encoding is "textToDisplay"?  My guess is that you have 16-bit encoded text and the ArcGIS code wants 8-bit, so the extra padding confuses the renderer.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the ".Text" property:

(NOTE: untested code)

```
public override void DrawDynamicLayer(esriDynamicDrawPhase DynamicDrawPhase, IDisplay iDisplay, IDynamicDisplay iDynamicDisplay) 
{
    if (this.m_textGlyph == null)
    {
        IBalloonCallout balloonCallout = new BalloonCalloutClass();
        balloonCallout.Style = esriBalloonCalloutStyle.esriBCSRoundedRectangle; //oval doesn't work 
        ITextElement pTextElement = new TextElementClass();
        TextSymbolClass textSymbolclass = new TextSymbolClass();
        IFormattedTextSymbol balloonCalloutTextSymbol = textSymbolclass as IFormattedTextSymbol;
        balloonCalloutTextSymbol.Background = balloonCallout as ITextBackground; 
        balloonCalloutTextSymbol.Font = ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Connection.Local.Converter.ToStdFont(new Font("Arial", 10.0f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular));

        pTextElement.Text = textToDisplay;

        m_textGlyph = dynamicGlyphFactory.CreateDynamicGlyph(balloonCalloutTextSymbol as ISymbol);
    }

    m_dynamicSymbolProperties.set_DynamicGlyph(esriDynamicSymbolType.esriDSymbolText, m_textGlyph);

}
```

It looks like the ArcEngine is "painting" each character with the balloon callout brush, rather than doing them all at once with a blob of text.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work